# mongodb java driver - Unable to use split in map function

Tags: java, mongodb

I've a table with documents in the format of

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("55867f3bfe2b0bea9c634ded"),
  "Best Site CR GU Party ID" : 14783,
  "Best Site CR GU Party Name" : "AUTOMOBILE INSURANCE COMPANY",
  "Product ID" : "C5500",
  "Product Family" : "C5000",
  "Product Description" : "5500 Chassis",
  "Best Site CR Party ID" : 45714558,
  "Best Site CR Party Name" : "INSURANCE COMPANY",
  "LDoS" : "4/27/2008",
  "LDoS FY" : 2008,
  "List Price $" : 3495,
  "Collector View" : "No"
}
```

and I'm using mongodb java driver 3.0.2. The intention is to aggregate the prices and number of documents for each month of every year in the collection. I've created the following function for map, which works on MongoVUE and fails with the java driver:

```
function Map() {
    var currentYr = new Date().getFullYear();
    var ldosMonth = this['LDoS'].split(/[//-]/)[0].replace(/^0+/, '');
    var key = {partyId: this['Best Site CR GU Party ID'], year: this['LDoS FY'], month: parseInt(ldosMonth)};

    emit(key, {price: this['List Price $'], count: 1});
}

Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 16722: 'exception: TypeError: Object 42582 has no method 'split'
    at Map (_funcs1:1:99) near '['LDoS']).split(/[//-]/)[0].replace(/^0+/' ' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "errmsg" : "exception: TypeError: Object 42582 has no method 'split'\n    at Map (_funcs1:1:99) near '['LDoS']).split(/[//-]/)[0].replace(/^0+/' ", "code" : 16722, "ok" : 0.0 }
    at com.mongodb.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:77)
```

How can I resolve this ? For the sake of completeness, here's the reduce function:

```
function Reduce(key, values) {
    var reduced = {price:0, count:0};

    values.forEach(function(val) {
        reduced.price += val.price;
        reduced.count += val.count; 
    });

    return reduced;
}

 String map = "function Map() {" +
            "var currentYr = new Date().getFullYear();" +
            "var ldosMonth = (this['LDoS']).split(/[//-]/)[0].replace(/^0+/, ''); " + // trim leading zero
            "var key = {partyId: this['Best Site CR GU Party ID'], year: this['LDoS FY'], month: parseInt(ldosMonth)};" +
            "var objToEmit = {price: this['List Price $'], count: 1};" +
            "emit(key, objToEmit);" +               
        "}";

        String reduce = "function Reduce(key, values) {" +
            "var reduced = {price:0, count:0};" +

            "values.forEach(function(val) {" +
                "reduced.price += val.price;" +
                "reduced.count += val.count;" + 
            "});" +

            "return reduced;" + 
        "}";

        MapReduceIterable<Document> output = dbCollection.mapReduce(map, reduce);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by refactoring the mapReduce call to

```
MapReduceIterable<Document> output = dbCollection.mapReduce(map, reduce)
                .finalizeFunction("function Finalize(key, reduced) {return reduced;}")
                .filter(Filters.and(new BasicDBObject("Best Site CR GU Party ID", guCrPartyId), Filters.or(new BasicDbObject("LDoS FY", 2015), new BasicDbObject("LDoS FY", 2016),new BasicDbObject("LDoS FY", 2017))
                .action(MapReduceAction.REPLACE);
```